# how to prepare cython submodules

Tags: cython

I have three questions, but related, and I not getting how can I split them well. I've found many information about those issues, like [submodule extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23841937/importerror-on-cython-submodule), [hierarchy](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/PackageHierarchy),  about an [empty *__init__.py* file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261147/cython-package-with-init-pyx-possible), and how to [cythonize multiple *pyx* files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826137/cython-setup-py-for-several-pyx). But when I try them together I cannot make them work.

I've prepared an [small repo](https://github.com/srgblnch/CythonPractice/tree/master/SingletonFactory) thinking in place together code samples of issues solved. I've check even the code of some of the [projects listed](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/projects) that uses cython, but still not getting how to does three things at the same time.

- Empty *__init__.py* file:

In a project (where all the files are *pyx* (and *pxd* ifneedbe)), with a *__init__.pyx* that includes all of them, when there is a *__init__.py* file, then import it doesn't load the "*.so*" but the empty init.

- cythonize multiple files:

When instead of prepare a *__init__.py* that includes all the elements of a module. Like:

```py
cythonize(['factory.pyx', 'version.pyx'])
```

the resulting "*.so*" import raises an exception:

```py
>>> import barfoo
(...)
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (PyInit_barfoo)
```

It would be related with the previous question if it is necessary to write something in *__init__.py*.

- Submodule:

In fact, this is the main question. The *singleton.pyx* would part of a submodule, lets say *utils* to be used from other elements in the module.

For the sample there is a submodule (simply called *subm*) added in the *setup.py* as another extension. I've placed earlier than the main one (I don't know if this really does any difference, I didn't see it).

```py
>>> import barfoo
>>> import barfoo.subm
(...)
ImportError: No module named 'barfoo.subm'
```

Separately, those recipes work, but together I cannot. The "*__init__.py*" seems to be necessary when there is a mix of "*py*" and "*pyx*" files. The examples explain how to cythonize with multiple files, but don't include the last key point for the import. And the submodules doesn't complete about how they can be imported from one place or another (import submodules when import the base one, or optional imports when they are specified).

Comment: Can you describe your file layout (before and after compilation)? I'm not 100% clear from the question but I think you're trying to compile multiple .pyx files to a single .so file, and that doesn't work. Each .pyx file needs to generate its own .so file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from [oz1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6610031/oz1) and [DavidW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4657412/davidw), I've got the [solution](https://github.com/srgblnch/CythonPractice/tree/0.0.3/SingletonFactory). Yes, those three things come together.

- **Very important** is the order when import in the *setup.py*. Even the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) doesn't say that the imports should be alphabetically sorted, there are other guide lines (like [reddit](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/PythonImportGuidelines)'s) that does and I usually follow:

When import first *cythonize* and then *setup*, will cause that when *cythonize(find_pyx())* is called, the result will be a list of *distutils.extension.Extension* objects.

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from Cython.Build import cythonize
```

*setuptools* must be imported before *cython* and then the result of *cythionize()* will be a list of *setuptools.extension.Extension* objects that can be passed to the *setup()* call.

- **Important** to understand the meanings of the *__init__*'s:

All the *__init__.pyx* files with includes has been removed and each *.pxy* file produces its own *.so* binary.

The main module and the submodules will exist as long as their directories contain the *__init__.py* file like happen with a pure python code.

In the example I've linked, the file *barfoo/__init__.py* is not empty because I want that *import barfoo* provides access to elements like *version()* or *Factory()*. Then, this *__init__.py* is who imports them like a normal pure python.

- For the submodule:

Similar for the *submodule* and its own *__init__.py* file. In this example the *import barfoo* will do a *from .factory import Factory*, who will call *from barfoo.subm import Bar*, then the *subm* will be available.

But if the submodule is not imported in this secondary way, the user will have access to it with calls like *import barfoo.subm*.

Answer (score 2):

Last night I saw your question, and made a simple example according to the [wiki](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/PackageHierarchy). But that question was deleted quickly.

Here is the example: https://github.com/justou/cython_package_demo

Make sure the settings of C compiler and python environment is correct, compile the pyx files by run:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

Usage is the same as python package:

```
from dvedit.filters import flip, inverse, reverse
flip.show()       # print: In flip call Core function
inverse.show()    # print: In inverse call Core function
reverse.show()    # print: In reverse call Core function
```

BTW, there is no need to create an `__init__.pyx`, you can do the ext_module importings in the `__init__.py` file

Comment: After post it yesterday I thought to do another iteration by myself and try to write it better. Sorry and thanks.

Comment: Almost, I think I've got something. The inplace left the so  file in the dvedit directory, but in my try left it one below (where the setup is).

Comment: @srgblnch I've been faced with the same problem in the past under windows. By updating setuptools, changing the directory, restarting pc, the problem gone away, I don't know wether it's a bug, and can't figure out why, even can't reproduce it now! I highly doubt it's a problem about 'path'.

Comment: With the comment on the question, I think, we've got the key about the directory and the \_\_init\_\_.py. *import dvedit* refers the python, but *import dvedit.core* refers the so comming from the core.pyx.

Comment: As a followup, I am trying to do something similar, except, I want to create a submodule with cdef definitions and pxd files. Now I want to use this submodule in another module that uses these cdef definitions. Unfortunately, I fail at doing so, and seem to be unable to access them without them being cpdef'd.